# Python Append to File in For Loop - Different Order Each Time

Tags: python, subprocess, append

I'm experiencing an exasperating problem here. I have a function `stdout_to_file` that reads from a dictionary of commands as follows. The function doesn't go through the different commands in order (or if it does, it doesn't append it to the file in question in order.

How do i make sure that it is consistently written in order of the dictionary each time? I've tried replacing `outfile.close()` with `outfile.flush()`

```
def stdout_to_file(filename, commands):
    """
    Clear file contents.
    """
    open(filename, 'a').truncate(0)
    try:
        with open(filename, 'a') as outfile:
            for command in commands.values():
                Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=outfile, stderr=outfile)
            outfile.close()
    except CalledProcessError as e:
        raise RuntimeError(
            "command '{}' return with error (code {}): {}".format(
                e.cmd, e.returncode, e.output
            )
        )
```

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: for python version 3.7 and above, you can assume the dictionary is ordered by the key-insert-time when iterating its keys.  While for version 3.6 and below, the key is not ordered as a tree structure.

Comment: By the way, if you provide a code that is either run-able, or specify date types of your input arguments, or provide an example of your dates, it would be easier for us to help you.

Comment: @MattDMo python3.9

Comment: @XinCheng  Thanks. It's actually reading from a .yaml file that contains various aws s3 ls commands. There are no dates involved here.

Comment: Oh it seems the dictionary `commands` uses dose not support order. which indicates the version is below 3.7.  Then the solution would be either to upgrade the python version or adapts the `commands` itself.   And cause I don't know how it is read, nor the format of its contents or example, that's all I can help with.

Comment: @XinCheng
No, if I print the dictionary values out ie. `commands`, they are in order. And it's Python 3.9. The issue is with the Python file reader / appender. The commands are simply `aws s3 ls` commands, and can be replaced by the shell `ls` for representation...

Answer (score 0):

It's because dictionaries aren't ordered. So everytime you run the program the dictionary will appear in a different index. Try either using nested lists, refering to specific keys/values of the dict, or just using .json which is essentially a dictionary.

Comment: Thanks. It's actually reading from a `.yaml` file that contains various `aws s3 ls` commands.

Comment: This isn't true by the way. Dictionary values are ordered by default in Python versions newer than 3.6